# SQL, avoiding to use inner select

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making an event app, one that allows people to create events and ticket types together that have a name, quantity and price, when a user purchases a ticket the purchase is inserted in a different table, the purchase includes the `event ID`, `ticket type ID` and other fields. At this point I want to fetch all my ticket types with the `ticket type name`, `quantity`, `price` and `available tickets`.

Here is a graphic look of my tables

```
TicketTypeTable
---------------------------------
|id |eventfk | name | qty | price|
|--------------------------------|


TicketSalesTable
----------------------------------------------
|id |userfk |eventfk | ticketype | qty | price|
|---------------------------------------------|`
```

And the output I want is

```
--------------------------------------------
|id |eventfk | name | qty |available | price|
|-------------------------------------------|
```

I can do this with an `inner select` like

```
select id
     , eventfk
     , name
     , qty (select count(*) from ticketsalestable) available
     , price 
  from tickettypetable
```

but this is bad for a large database...and it's just bad regardless of the situation.

Anyone know a better way out?

I also tried using a JOIN but am stuck

`SELECT t.id, t.eventfk, t.name, t.quantity, t.price FROM tickettypetable t LEFT JOIN ticketsalestable s ON s.eventfk = t.eventfk WHERE t.eventfk = 10`

Comment: What does the execution plan say? Have you tried a join? Any difference?

Comment: `select count(*) from ticketsalestable` is very fast on MyISAM  engine even with millions or billions off records because the row count is in the header of the .myd file .  But indeed slow on InnoDB.. Not sure how one would go to speed this up caching if possible would be a solution.

Comment: @jarlh see my update. I tried a join but stuck not sure how it should be written

Comment: @RaymondNijland You might be right, but it's good practice to avoid `inner selects`

Comment: "but it's good practice to avoid inner selects " @Uncle inner selects earn't that bad.. unless they are co-related subqueries which tends to optimize badly in MySQL.. Unless you mean the inner select can be totally avoided here in this case and query

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes you are right. I know I can solve this with an inner select but looking for a way to avoid it

Comment: @Uncle it is hard to suggest a better optimized query without knowing the table structure for every table involved in the question ( use `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table>` to get it ) also example data and expected output should be included in the question...

Comment: Perhaps join to a sub-query with the count? F.e.  `select id, eventfk, name, qty, c.available, price from tickettypetable cross join (select count(*) as available from ticketsalestable) c`

Comment: I can't figure out what you want.  There is no column called `available`.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on `Turo's` answer I modified it and came up with this

`SELECT t.id, t.name, t.quantity, IF(t.price = 0,'FREE',t.price), (t.quantity - IFNULL(s.sold, 0)) as available FROM tickettypetb t LEFT JOIN (select sl.eventfk, sl.tickettypefk, COUNT(sl.eventfk) as sold from salestb sl GROUP BY sl.tickettypefk ORDER BY sl.tickettypefk DESC) s ON s.tickettypefk = t.id AND s.eventfk = t.eventfk WHERE t.eventfk = 22 GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY t.id DESC`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a join with the aggregate of ticketsalestable, something like

```
SELECT t.id, t.eventfk, t.name, t.quantity, t.price, (t.qty - s.sold) as available FROM tickettypetable t LEFT JOIN 
    ( select eventfk, tickettype, sum(qty) as sold from ticketsalestable group by eventfk, tickettype) s
    ON s.eventfk = t.eventfk and t.id = s.tickettype
 WHERE t.eventfk = 10
```

Dependent on the optimizer it could be faster to add the where criteria also to the  aggregate

```
SELECT t.id, t.eventfk, t.name, t.quantity, t.price, (t.qty - s.sold) as available FROM tickettypetable t LEFT JOIN 
    ( select eventfk, tickettype, sum(qty) as sold from ticketsalestable group by eventfk, tickettype where eventfk = 10) s
    ON s.eventfk = t.eventfk and t.id = s.tickettype
 WHERE t.eventfk = 10
```

*EDIT*
ticketype is join-criteria, too

Comment: this is good, but it sums all the tickets ever sold by an event regardless of the ticketype and puts the total in the first row. the other rows get null as the total

Comment: You wrote almost nothing about the tickettype, how to regard it?

Comment: the ticket type is the `foreign key` of the `ticketTypeTable` in `ticketSalesTable` it shows how many of a given ticket was sold.

Comment: Ah, so tickettype in the SalesTable is corresppndeing to id in the Type Table? You should have mentioned that!

Comment: Oh, you mentioned it, but i didn't get it right away

Comment: Sorry about that.